# Condition for negative Thevenin resistance

Tags: resistance, thevenin

Is there any particular condition or relation between the impedances and the dependent sources in a circuit by which the Thevenin resistance turns out to be negative?

Comment: If the original circuit does not contain a resistor with a negative value then I do not see how the Thevenin equivalent circuit would have a resistor with a negative value. My guess is that you changed the direction of a current or voltage somewhere where you should not have.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie Sorry, but I do not agree. Imagine a resistor R, connected in series to a VCVS, that outputs a voltage Vout = 2*Vx, where Vx is the voltage on the series of R+VCVS. Imagine it's connected so that Vx = I * R + Vout = I * R + 2 * Vx. Then, solving for Vx, you have: -Vx = I * R. The impedance of the series is negative: - R. This can be easily done using an operational.

Comment: you get negative Z or impedance inversion with negative feedback such that gain is now Av=Zf/-Zin  such that impedance of Zin (source to Vin-) or a Transimpedance amplifier.

Comment: Absolutely, in some oscillator topologies the design goal is provide -R to the LC tank to overcome the equivalent R of the tank circuit

Comment: @next-hack In my opinion such a series circuit is **not** a negative impedance. Assume I = 1 A, R = 1 ohm, Vx = 1, that would make Vout = 2 V. Now I increase Vout to 3 V, then both Vr and Vx will become 1.5 V and I will become 1.5 A. So the current **increases** when I increase the voltage. That means I see a **positive value** resistor. If it were a negative resistor then the current would have to **decrease**.

Comment: I have designed such negative R oscillators where the negative R is made using a cross-coupled pair of NPNs. Then the negative resistance is **in parallel** with the LC tank. In theory one could also place a negative value resistor **in series** with the LC tank and that would also make it oscillate. In practice the -R value of the series case is impractical so I've only used the parallel -R sofar. Parallel or series are also Thevenin equivalents but they do not change the sign of the resistor's value.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie resistance is defined as the DC voltage across the "resistor" divided by the current it flows into, using the passive sign convention. It's the well known Ohm's Law.  If V is positive but I is negative, then R is negative. With your concept you're limiting only to those non-linear devices/systems, which exhibit a negative differential resistance (i.e. instead of considering V/I you consider dV/dI. However, if the component is linear - i.e. V= R * I -, then V/I = dV/dI).

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_resistance. Search for Fig. 4 or "negative linear" or "active resistance". You're limiting only on the Fig. 2 case. (actually it is the more general case, yet it does not exclude the Fig. 4 case).

Comment: @next-hack No, that is not how it works. What I wrote applies to linear systems. The way that you define the direction of a current through a resistor does not make it have a negative value. If the current through a **positive** value resistor is **positive** then the voltage **must** be positive as well. Equally if the current is **negative** the voltage must be **negative** as well. You cannot violate that and say that the resistor suddenly has become negative.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie. Yes it works in this way. You're confusing linear systems with non linear one. Go and calculate the input impedance of this circuit then:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_impedance_converter

Comment: @next-hack I can assure you I'm not confusing linear and non-linear systems. **Show me** where what **I wrote** only applies to **non-linear systems**. I fail to see how linear vs non linear relates to the discussion as Thevenin is for linear circuits only. There's nothing wrong with what is written on the wikipedia pages.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie I told you're just limiting to strictly non linear systems. Anyway, did you try to analyze that circuit? What's the input resistance, assuming R1=R2 and a positive R3? What does it yield? I give you a guess: -R3. Negative.

Comment: @next-hack Oh, you're still stuck on your circuit not having a negative impedance ? Geez. I probably misinterpreted the circuit you described. Anyway, of course you're right that those wikipedia circuits have a negative impedance (that's what it says) and that that would be the same if you replace the opamp correctly with a vcvs. The question of OP is, is you have a negative R and make it's Thevenin equivalent, is the R still negative ? Since a dissipating R cannot suddenly change into a power delivering R I'd say: yes the sign remains.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie. Quoting myself. "Imagine it's connected so that Vx = I * R + Vout = I * R + 2 * Vx.", with the passive sign convention, that equation unambiguously describes the dipole I was referring to. If you calculate the Thevenin equivalent of such dipole, you get a 0V source, and a -R resistor. The original resistor still does dissipate, but the presence of that VCVS makes the final dipole as if the dipole were not dissipative. The Thevenin equivalent resistor has "nothing to do" with the original one.

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume that the expression "Thevenin impedance" means the impedance seen at a terminal pair ideally measuring it by applying a voltage and sensing the current. So, it's the equivalent impedance (or resistance, to simplify) seen at accessible terminals.

Part 1: some considerations on sufficient criteria and history of NIC (Negative Immittance Converter)
Part 2: example

**Part 1**

An ideal NIC is an active two-port which gives a negative input impedance Zin=-k*ZL, where ZL is a load terminating it at the other port. In the example below R3 is that load, whereas the usual scheme (e.g. to design active filters based on cascaded NIC stages) identifies "Node C" as output.

If expressed in hybrid parameters,

Zin = h11 - h12*h21 / (h22 + 1/ZL)

that gives two necessary conditions: h11=h22=0 and h12*h21=k.

Compensation is also possible for non-ideal NICs to become ideal NICs, so that conditions are relaxed for a non-ideal NIC, provided that compensation is added. Compensating elements are passive: simply speaking they compensate for either h11 or h22 not being zero, or both.

The NIC needs an active element, that in principle may be one among gyrators, negative immittance inverters, or controlled sources. OpAmp or transistors implementing controlled sources are the modern most common solution (e.g. negative resistance oscillators).

Stability is a known problem of NIC, especially when parasitics play a role, e.g. at very high frequency. See [RADIOENGINEERING,Segovia-Vargas et al.](https://www.radioeng.cz/fulltexts/2016/16_03_0409_0418.pdf) for a recent paper on stability of NICs for microwaves.

**Part2**

An example of negative resistance phenomenon is the Negative Resistance Converter, that may be built around an OpAmp exploiting two facts: the use of the positive input terminal for some feedback and the OA output driving the circuit so that the voltage difference between its input terminals is so small to be 0.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ftw37M.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Assumption1: OpAmp input currents are negligible (I+=I-=0)
Assumption2: the voltage difference between OA input terminals is zero, i.e.  V+ = V-

Applying the input voltage V_in we will see current I_1 flow through R1, given by:

I_1 = (V_in - V_B)/R1     (1)

V_B is the output voltage of the OpAmp that will adapt to

I_2 is given by:

I_2 = (V_C - V_B)/R2     (2)

and I_3 is given by:

I_3 = V_C/R3       (3)

The objective is to determine input current I_in=I_1 by solving the above equations. Using assumption1 we say that I_3=I_2; using assumption2 we say that V_C=V_in.

We can put (3) into (2):

I_2 = (R3*I_2 - V_B)/R2     (4)

V_B is needed to replace it in eq. (1); thus:

V_B = (R3-R2)*I_2      (5)

But, also V_B can be determined from eq. (2) and (3) invoking both assumptions on OA:

I_2 = I_3 => (V_in - V_B)/R2 = V_in/R3     (6)

V_B = (R2/R3-1)*V_in     (7)

Eq (7) into eq. (1) gives:

I_1 = (V_in - (R2/R3-1)*V_in)    (8)

V_in = -R3/R2*I_in    (9)

that by definition shows a negative resistance value when the equivalent input resistance is "measured" as R_in = V_in / I_in.

Of course, a check shall be made that the OA is working in the linear region (V_B is not exceeding is capability, namely supply voltage less a margin), and that the two assumptions hold: assumption1 holds if we do not want to see negative resistance for very very small I_in currents (let's say a JFET OpAmp is satisfactory down to some nA); assumption2 depends on the open loop gain of the OpAmp, so at high frequency some deviations are unavoidable (a JFET good OpAmp might have a hundred MHz of GBW, such as AD8039 or AD8065).